# Is this kind of sediment location sampling on river acceptable?

Tags: geochemistry, sedimentology

Yesterday, we performed a sediment sampling along both sides of a river. On various research papers, it seems that they always made it successfully to perform the sampling at both left and right side of the river on a single site, meanwhile in my case, it is quite impossible to me to sample the opposite side of the river on same site because it has a very steep angle and on other site there was a big excavator digging up those sediments on one side. The sampling relied mostly on the muddy, but accessible, flood sediment deposits. There was no previous study related to the river I performed at so I have no previous information regarding the nature of the deposits on each side.

At the end, I performed the sampling like this:

[image]

I was asked to perform the sampling at both left and right side of the river (without any detail here) and those sediments will be acid-digested and its heavy metal concentrations will be measured using an atomic absorption spectrophotometer.

Is this sampling acceptable? Is there any reference that this sampling is acceptable or not, considering that struggles before?

Thank you.

Comment: Whether this is acceptable is inevitably subjective. What is the aim of sampling? What level of variation might be expected in the heavy metals, and would only sampling where there are shallow banks bias results.? The latter probably depends on the river itself.  For research purposes the important thing will be to recognize and acknowledge the uncertainties in the adopted sampling strategy. Health and safety is always an important factor.